# Meaning of * and ^ in a formula is multiplication and power, respectively in R

Tags: r, modeling

I wrote a model like this in R:

```
model2 = nls(Height ~ ((Diameter)^2/(a*(Diameter)^2+b*Diameter+c))+1.30, data = dat1, start = list(a = 1, b=1, c=1), algorithm="port")
```

I used `*` for multiplication, `^` for power, and `/` for division. Is that right ?

Comment: You can check with `?"*"`.

Answer (score 1):

yes, check here [link](http://www.statmethods.net/management/operators.html)

```
 **Operator Description**
   +        addition
   -        subtraction
   *        multiplication
   /        division
 ^ or **    exponentiation
 x %% y     modulus (x mod y) 5%%2 is 1
 x %/% y    integer division 5%/%2 is 2
```

Comment: Thank you all. I have another question. How can I enter "e", "base of the natural logarithm approximately equal to 2.718" in the model in R? the program assumes that as an coefficient.

Comment: I think you can use exp() function.  check this .. http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/exp.php

Comment: Is following instruction correct for the model"Height=1.30+a*(1-e^(b*Diameter))^c"?   y=Height , x=Diameter   # model3 = nls(Height ~ 1.30+a*I(1-exp(b*Diameter))^c, data = dat1, start = list(a = 1, b=1, c=1), algorithm="port")

Answer (score 0):

Within formulas, `^` gives you all interactions terms to the order specified. Hence, in your case `(Diameter)^2` would be equivalent to `Diameter*Diameter` which is why the notation makes sense. If you want it to be interpreted literally you can use `I()` around the term.

See e.g. [this page.](http://artsci.wustl.edu/~jgill/slides/model.syntax.txt) under special characters and `?I`.